# React-Leaflet app suddently stopped working Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, leaflet, mern

Need your help! The problem is that my app suddently stopped working. It did showed markers previously.But now I see  this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null" It is very strange because it WORKED WELL and all I did I put them into archive but when it was unzipped it didn't work anymore. I provide some code if it helps but I assure you I did nothing with it.

```
 componentDidMount(){
 this.loadData()
 }
loadData() {
// fetch('/api/issues').then(response => {
  fetch('/api/issues').then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then(data => {
      this.setState({markers:data.records});
    });
  } else {
    response.json().then(error => {
      alert("Failed to fetch issues:" + error.message)
    });
  }
}).catch(err => {
  alert("Error in fetching data from server:", err);
});


}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Map center={{lat:51.505,lng:-0.09}} 
            zoom={13}>
         <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; 
      <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
         /> 

        {this.state.markers.map((position,_id) => 
          <Marker 
             key={_id} 
             position={position}>
          </Marker>
         )}
      </Map>    
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution turned out to be very simple. It all happened because some of the fields in mongoDB under keys "lat" and " lng" were empty since I haven't provide any value. So the problem have nothing to do neither wiith the code, nor with dependencies.